# dll .Net framework with WCF in .NET 8

Tags: wcf, dll, .net-8.0

For historical reasons, I have to use a .NET Framework dll in my project .NET 8 in order to manage business issues.

The problem is the dll use System.ServiceModel because it use WCF to call distant server.

I can add as reference my dll without problem in VS2022.

But when I execute my project, when I call a method from the dll, an exception appears because it try to call WCF layer :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The specified file
> could not be found.'

I try to add packages from nuget like System.ServiceModel.Primitives or System.ServiceModel.Http without success.

I don't have access to the source code of this dll. There is any way to use it in a .NET 8 project ?

Comment: There is [WCF for .NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/), if I understand you correctly - then you can try migrating to it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, based on your bug report, it seems that the version is too low.

.NET 8 is a new platform. You should upgrade the versions of these two packages to the latest in order to use them.

[System.ServiceModel.Primitives 8.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Primitives/) and [System.ServiceModel.Http 8.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Http) exist on Nuget. You can uninstall the version you installed and reinstall the new version to try again.

Comment: This is already being done. System.ServiceModel.Primitives does not exist in .Net Framework

Comment: Try installing [CoreWCF.Primitives](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreWCF.Primitives/#supportedframeworks-body-tab)